# Import csv to influx

Tags: csv, import, command-line-interface, influxdb

I need to correct some data in my Influx DB and succesfully exported using:

`influx -database graf -username graf -password graf  -format csv -execute "select * from net2 where "host" = 'ahc' and time <= 1698222663001569086" > ahc.export`

but I cannot figure out how to reimport the corrected csv. Amongst many, I've tried

`influx -database graf -username graf -password graf -execute "write net2 -f ahc.import.csv"`

but I get

`ERR: error parsing query: found WRITE, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1`

None of which seem to relate to what I need to do...